# Visual Studio 2008 Profiler - C++ Library Problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, profiler

I have two VS2008 C++ projects. One builds a static library (.lib). The other uses that library and builds an executable. I would like to profile the .exe, but am primarily interested in the profile of the code inside the library. When I run the profiler in the .exe project, I only get stats on functions in that project, and the library code is not covered at all. Do I need to do something special when building the library to get it profiled as well?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find ways to speed up your program (as opposed to just getting general timing numbers and invocation counts, call-graph, etc.), then the [random halt technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) works just fine in VS, library or not. I use it all the time.